# Firebase JS Authentication cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm intending on using PHP to manage my application. I'm using JS to register and signup to auth. I then intend on using cookies to get this in PHP.

I just wondered how Firebase keeps its authentication peristant. I assumed cookies but when I checked there were no cookies from that site.

If there is cookies, what are the titles etc as I want to use them in the PHP.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase uses local storage.  You can access the auth information using:

```
localStorage.getItem(`firebase:authUser:${YOUR_FIREBASE_API_KEY}:[DEFAULT]`)
```

[image: Local Storage]